# Can't get my custom UITableViewCell to show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a TableView xib and all the delegates and datasource seem to be running fine.
If I set `self.textLabel.text`, it displays the generic number of tableviews correctly, but I need to have my custom TableViewCell showing.

I created a HistoryCell.xib that has just a tableviewcell in it.
I created a UITableViewCell class "HistoryCell.h/HistoryCell.m" and it is set as the file owner of HistoryCell.xib.
I connected the UILabels to the HistoryCell.h
`UILabel statusLabel`
`UILabel nameLabel`
`UILabel timeLabel`

In my main ViewController class int he `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

I am putting in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"historyCellType";
HistoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[HistoryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.nameLabel.text = @"Donald Duck";

return cell;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You may take a look at the tutorial at the link, however it's basically what @veddermatic answered. http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should register the nib like this (probably in viewDidLoad):

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HistoryCell" bundle:nil ] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"historyCellType"];
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, use this new way where you don't need the if cell == nil clause:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

HistoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"historyCellType" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.nameLabel.text = @"Donald Duck";

return cell;
```

}

Comment: That is smart! However, It keeps crashing on the first line for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x755dcd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'

Comment: @Alan, That probably means you have something wrong in your xib file. make sure your outlet is really called nameLabel, and that you don't have any yellow warning triangles if you right click on the cell to show the window with all the connections. also, put a log in cellForRowAtIndexPath after you define cell, to log cell, and make sure you get back a HistoryCell.

Comment: there isn't any code, so I am guessing there is some sort of configuration problem... Is the UITableViewCell suppose to be inside a view? I ONLY have the TableViewCell inside the xib and the 3 UILabels inside the UITableViewCell. Also, is the File Owner suppose to be the main controller class or the "HistoryCell.h/HistoryCell.m" 

I checked the naming and they are named correctly and when I hover over the connection dot in HistoryCell.h it highlights the correct labels in the xib...

Comment: @Alan, yes it should be a bare UITableViewCell (or subclass) in the xib. As for the File's owner, I usually just leave that as NSObject, but I don't think that matters. Did you change the class of the cell in the xib to HistoryCell? If not , you should.

Comment: ahh X_X I have no idea what's going on. Yes, I do have the UITableViewCell set to HistoryCell and the UILabels connected to the HistoryCell.h using the ctrl-drag. 

I still get the same error.

Comment: @Alan, have you done a Clean? Shut down Xcode and relaunched? Deleted the app from the simulator? Try all those if you haven't yet, and see if that helps. If not I can take a look at it if you want to send it to me.

Comment: You are the best! I am not sure what happened. I closed xCode and restarted my computer and then reopened it and ran it, crashed. I deleted all the UILabels and remade them and it works! weird. Thank you so much for your continued help!!!!!

Comment: Probably, I figured out the exact reason. If you copy a `UILable` to create another one, it will crash. But if you drag and drop a brand new `UILabel` every time, it should be fine. That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to deserialize the actual XIB data:

```
HistoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *cellnib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoryXIBName" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (HistoryCell *)[cellnib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Otherwise it's just using a "Default" cell.

**EDIT**: Also, if you are using storyboards, dynamic cell prototypes remove the need to create cells from NIB files (in case that's an option for you.)

**EDIT The 2nd:**
You can try this as well (this assumes you are using ARC):

```
HistoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    HistoryCell *aNewCell = [[HistoryCell alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryXIBName" bundle:nil];
    cell = (HistoryCell *)*aNewCell.view;
}
```

There's another method using outlets to your cell in the containing view's XIB file that's a bit more involved that I used to use when iOS4 was current. If the edited version isn't' working for you, I'll dig out an old project and remember how I did it.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your prompt help! 

I tried this code, but the app is crashing when it gets there:


2013-03-21 17:00:36.212 AppName[3133:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<detailThreeViewController 0x1007fcf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'

Comment: Alan: I edited in a 2nd method to try. Also, can you tell me what version of iOS you are targeting?

Comment: I am targeting for 6.1. Ok, I will give it a try.

Comment: Thank you.
The new code does not compile on`HistoryCell *aNewCell = [[HistoryCell alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryCellView" bundle:nil];` it gives "No visible @interface for 'HistoryCell' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'

Also, is my HistoryCell xib suppose to have a TableViewCell inside a View? My HistoryCell xib only has the bare TableView Cell on it.

Comment: If you are targeting 6.1, you can use the `registerNib` method in rdelmar's answer. I assumed because you were using NIBs you were back on 4.X.  As I said in my answer, Storyboards do all this for you, so if you can use them, you should.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I am doing paging using UIScrollView and unfortunately when I learned there wasn't any good documentation that I could find to do it based solely on the Storyboard. I still don't know how to insert multiple views for paging via storyboard. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use tableViewCell with xib, while instantiation load from xib.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"historyCellType";
    HistoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HistoryCell"
                                         owner:nil
                                       options:nil]lastObject];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Donald Duck";

    return cell;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell1"; 
    customcell *cell =
      (customcell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if (cell==nil)  {

    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Customcell" bundle:nil] 
               forCellReuseIdentifier:cellidentifier]; 

    cell =
     (customcell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier 
                 forIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row 
                                                  inSection:indexPath.section]];   
    }   

    return cell; 
}
```